# Automatic Login with OpenID

Tags: support, openid

Maybe this is superuser, but is there a firefox plugin of any sort that will allow it so when I go to any of the trilogy sites it will just auto log me in?  So I don't have enter my myopenid URL, or password, or anything like that.

Comment: You aren't throwing away your cookies are you?

Comment: Do you have cookies or something turned off in your browser? I don't know how it's cached, but I never have to login again to SO and friends unless I mess with the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You have to log into OpenID?

Perhaps you should try using [MyOpenID](https://www.myopenid.com/), I cannot even remember the last time I had to log in on any of the sites on any of my machines.

#### Edit:

Also check to make sure you are not clearing cookies when you exit your browser. Stop that sillyness.

Comment: @Kyle - Sounds like you've told your browser to clear cookies when you close it. You might want to turn that off (see http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options+window+-+Privacy+panel)

Comment: Solution in Firefox was: Edit :: Preferences :: Privacy :: Clear History When Firefox Closed :: Settings :: Uncheck Active Logins.